# Solve differential equation $f''''(x)=f'''(x)f''(x)f'(x)f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I met this DE recently, and I am utterly befuddled at how to solve it
$$f''''(x)=f'''(x)f''(x)f'(x)f(x)$$
I tried this:
$$\frac{f''''(x)}{f'''(x)}=f''(x)f'(x)f(x)$$
$$\ln|f'''(x)|=c_1+\int f(x)f'(x)f''(x)dx$$
I do not know how to solve the right side, though. Integration by parts?

Plaese help.

Comment: You need to be careful hanging around in the dark alleyways of real analysis. Try $f(x) = 0$ to start.

Comment: As a start, find the polynomial solutions $f'''(x) = 0$ .

Comment: Next you can try to find a power-law solution: try $f(x) = ax^n$ and try to solve for $a$ and $n$.

Comment: @Winther - with non-integer $n$ :)

Comment: @Winther I don't really know how to do the second one...

Comment: Insert that expression into the ODE. This will give you something like $Ax^k = B x^m$. For this to hold for all $x$ you need $k=m$ and $A=B$ which gives you two equations that determines $a$ and $n$. (as a technical note: this turns out only to be a valid solution if $x=0$ is not in the domain)

Comment: @Winther ok I'll give it a shot when I can, and tell you what I get

Comment: One reason this kind of thing feels so unnatural (as in how would this DE ever naturally arise?). Say $x$ is measured in $\mathrm{u}$ and $f(x)$ is measured in $\mathrm{v}$. Then the the units on the left are $\frac{\mathrm{v}}{\mathrm{u}^4}$ and the units on the right are $\frac{\mathrm{v}^4}{\mathrm{u}^6}$. If there were some physical constant $a$ value with units $\frac{\mathrm{u}^2}{\mathrm{v}^3}$ and $f^{(4)}=af^{(3)}f''f'f$, that brings it back in line.

Comment: @alex.jordan interesting... I just came up with the DE, but I like your approach. Tell me if it gives you anything.

Comment: I think I just meant that if there is a way to solve this, then it should also be solvable when there is a parameter $a$ out front. I don't think that putting the $a$ there will make it easier (or harder) to solve.

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c~~$ is a solution. Winther already hinted at it though

Comment: Since it involves a fourth derivative, should we expect four arbitrary constants in the solution?  So Winther's / Yurly's solution is not the complete general solution.

Comment: @badjohn potentially. I have, however, solved DE's via multiple rounds of integration, where solutions only have one arbitrary constant. Especially with this one, since there is a bit of multiplication going on, there might not be that many constants in the solution. But then again, you never know 'till you know

Comment: @clathratus Interesting.  I may ask my own question along those lines.  One interesting approach may be to set some initial condition that this solution does not offer e.g. $f'''(0) = 1$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{\frac{63}{4}x^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the first few terms of the series solution at $0$, according to Maple.
$$
f \left( x \right) ={\it a_0}+{\it a_1}\,x+{\it a_2}\,{x}^{2}+{
\it a_3}\,{x}^{3}\\+{\frac {{\it a_3}\,{\it a_2}\,{\it a_1}\,{\it 
a_0}}{2}}\,{x}^{4}\\+ \left( {\frac {{{\it a_0}}^{2}{{\it a_1}}^{2}{{
\it a_2}}^{2}{\it a_3}}{5}}+{\frac {3\,{\it a_0}\,{\it a_1}\,{{
\it a_3}}^{2}}{10}}+{\frac {{\it a_0}\,{{\it a_2}}^{2}{\it a_3}}{5
}}+{\frac {{{\it a_1}}^{2}{\it a_2}\,{\it a_3}}{10}} \right) {x}^{5
}\\+ \left( {\frac {{{\it a_0}}^{3}{{\it a_1}}^{3}{{\it a_2}}^{3}{
\it a_3}}{15}}+{\frac {2\,{{\it a_3}}^{2}{\it a_2}\,{{\it a_1}}^{2
}{{\it a_0}}^{2}}{5}}+{\frac {{{\it a_0}}^{2}{\it a_1}\,{{\it a_2}
}^{3}{\it a_3}}{5}}+{\frac {{\it a_0}\,{{\it a_1}}^{3}{{\it a_2}}^
{2}{\it a_3}}{10}}+{\frac {3\,{{\it a_3}}^{2}{\it a_0}\,{\it a_2}
}{10}}+{\frac {{{\it a_1}}^{2}{{\it a_3}}^{2}}{10}}+{\frac {{{\it 
a_2}}^{2}{\it a_1}\,{\it a_3}}{10}} \right) {x}^{6}\\+\dots 
$$
With $4$ arbitrary constants, as expected.  But, again as expected, it is not a linear combination of 4 independent solutions.

**added**  How'd you get this?
Maple.  Outputs are long, so I omit them.

`>DE:=diff(f(x),x,x,x,x)=diff(f(x),x,x,x)*diff(f(x),x,x)*diff(f(x),x)*f(x);`
`>Order:=7;SS:=dsolve({DE,f(0)=a_0,D(f)(0)=a_1,`
`(D@@2)(f)(0)=2*a_2,(D@@3)(f)(0)=6*a_3},f(x),series,x=0);`
`>latex(%);`

Comment: Wow! is there a 'closed form' for this solution (series, hypergeometric function, special function, etc.)? Also: how'd you get this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=\dfrac{df}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{df}{dx}=u\dfrac{du}{df}$

$\dfrac{d^3f}{dx^3}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(u\dfrac{du}{df}\right)=\dfrac{d}{df}\left(u\dfrac{du}{df}\right)\dfrac{df}{dx}=\left(u\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^2\right)u=u^2\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^2$

$\dfrac{d^4f}{dx^4}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(u^2\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^2\right)=\dfrac{d}{df}\left(u^2\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^2\right)\dfrac{df}{dx}=\left(u^2\dfrac{d^3u}{df^3}+4u\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3\right)u=u^3\dfrac{d^3u}{df^3}+4u^2\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3$

$\therefore u^3\dfrac{d^3u}{df^3}+4u^2\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3=\left(u^2\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^2\right)u\dfrac{du}{df}uf$

$u^2\dfrac{d^3u}{df^3}+4u\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3=fu^3\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+fu^2\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3$

$u^2\dfrac{d^3u}{df^3}+(4-fu^2)u\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+(1-fu^2)\left(\dfrac{du}{df}\right)^3=0$

Comment: Wow. I can't solve this